How to implement scoped services in tabs, (preferably) in a WPF application using Prism?
I'm creating a WPF application using the Prism framework and have run into an issue with dependency injection scopes. My application contains multiple tabs (2, at least for now), each with identical views and ViewModels.
It's like every tab is an instance of the software that is inside of the tab itself.
Here's the specific requirement:

Each tab should have its own scope (or any other way to achieve the same result).
Within a tab, I want to inject the same instance of a service across the multiple ViewModels in that tab.
The instance of the service must be different between tabs.

Note: I would like to avoid solutions that require assigning a unique ID to each tab and managing state through dictionaries like username["tab_uuid_1"]. Ideally, each ViewModel should remain unaware that it is being scoped or separated by tabs. I'm open to another solution, even if it doesn't involve using the Prism framework!

For example:

Tab 1 should have a unique instance of the services shared among its ViewModels.
Tab 2 should have a separate instance of the same services, also shared among its ViewModels.

I'm not sure how to associate a scope with a specific tab. The tabs can dynamically or statically created (it's not important!).

@ASh my intention was to avoid ambiguity and ensure the question is as specific as possible. My question is: I just don't know how/where to define what is a "scope", there is no such code I can show. Also, I felt your reply came across as passive-aggressive, which was disheartening (maybe that's one of the reasons why this website is   recently?). I’m a chill guy genuinely seeking guidance and solutions, don't be that mad :)

[mcve] for this question would be a code which creates a view with multiple tabs, definition of all involved view model and DI setup - where service is injected but it doesn't fulfill all requirements. all that code will allow to give specific suggestions.

"the question is as specific as possible" - I don't think so since even concrete DI container is not mentioned

"Tabs" are an illusion; it's just multiple "views"; made easier with user controls ("multiple instances").

Register the services scoped as needed at your resolution root and in your main view model, create the tabs' view models in scopes.
I'd put the creation of the view models in a service to contain the container usage as much as possible.

Thank you! I just had to _regionManager.Regions["xyz"].Add(_containerProvider.Resolve<ViewName>(), null, true); in the MainWindow's ViewModel. (the 3rd parameter here, true, is what I was looking for, i.e. createRegionManagerScope)

You could even drop the regions altogether if you don't need the automagic view discovery and string-based navigation.

Hey @Haukinger I don't get what you mean  could you explain please

@LorenzoMogicato I wanted to say that you can very much just bind a ContentControl to a view model property and define a data template instead of creating a region for it and then navigating.  ContentControl Content="{Binding XyzViewModel} and XyzViewModel = new Something(); is more straight forward than ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" and RegisterForNavigation<ViewType,ViewModelType>("viewname") and RequestNavigate. That is, if there's no requirement that prevents the former.

That makes sense indeed, thanks for your help
